# How do I create and save an unknown amount of variables to Django Model?

Tags: python, django, model

I am working with the twitter api via tweepy and I am unsure how to save an unknown quantity of media urls to a model object.

The media section is where I am stuck. Some tweets will have media urls and some wont, while some may have numerous media urls.

How do I create an unknown amount of media url variables and then how do I add that to the update_or_create?

I appreciate all your help... been trying to figure this out for awhile now.

```py
    user = api.get_user(screen_name=team)
        timeline = tweepy.Cursor(
            api.user_timeline, id=team, exclude_replies=True,
            include_rts=False).items(20)

    handle = user['screen_name']
    location = user['location']
    description = user['description']

    for tweet in timeline:
        tweet_id = tweet['id']
        date = tweet['created_at']
        content = tweet['text']

    `This is where I am stuck`

        if 'media' in tweet.entities:
            for media in tweet.extended_entities.media:
                url = media['media_url']

    Tweets.objects.update_or_create(
        tweet_id=tweet_id, defaults={
            'handle': handle,
            'tweet_id': tweet_id,
            'location': location,
            'description': description,
            'date': date,
            'content': content,
            'url': url}
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible options:

a) if you are using PostgreSQL database you can use ArrrayField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) to make an array of strings representing urls

b) you can use secondary table that has relation to this one and put urls there

I sometimes use first one (but it is limited to Postgres) and sometimes the second one (which does make more sense in relation database)

Comment: I think the ArrayField is what I was looking for. Thanks!